# Extraer datos de un JSONP para transformarlos en HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cors, jsonp

Quiero cargar 20 productos de Amazon y se presenten cada uno en su box o caja con en las etiquetas DIV=Content -> SECTION -> y luego cada resultado en su DIV con la fotografía, descripción y link al producto, el JSON lo trato como JSONP por ser data de otro dominio. La idea no es llamar a la API sino aprovechar los resultados de amazon-adsystem. Hasta ahora he logrado esto:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="images"></div>
 
<script>
(function() {
  var callback = "https://ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?callback=search_callback&MarketPlace=ES&Operation=GetResults&InstanceId=0&dataType=jsonp&TemplateId=MobileSearchResults&ServiceVersion=20070822&SearchIndex=All&multipageStart=0&multipageCount=20&callback=search_callback&_=1588281576832";
  
    $.getJSON( callback, {
        Keywords: "ollas"
    })
    .done(function( data )
    {
        $.each( data.results, function( i, results) {
            $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", results.ImageUrl ).appendTo("#images");
            html.innerHTML+="<p>ImageUrl"+results.ImageUrl;
            html.innerHTML+="<p>Title="+results.Title;
            if ( i === 20 ) {
                return false;
            } 
        });
    });
})();
</script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

**Los valores a extraer serían:**
-Title
-ImageUrl
-Price
-ASIN ->(https:// www.amazon.es/dp/{ASIN}?tag={TAG-AFF}..
-Rating
-TotalReviews

Hasta allí he llegado, me he enredado intentando mostrar los datos en HTML, ¿alguna idea?, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Quizas esto ayude, a mi no me funciono con $.getJSON pero puede talvez funcionarte sin jQuery: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp

Comment: El $getJSON lee la url y agrega la keyword, de hecho lo puedes ver en la herramienta para desarrollador por ejemplo en Chrome, en network o en la consola, falta es resolver cómo lee los valores y los pasa a HTML

Comment: Pero a mi eso no me funciono...? intente leerlo asi tal cual con tu codigo y no funciono...

Comment: Abre en tu navegador con botón derecho "Inspeccionar", vas a Network o Red y verás al final de la url https://ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com...etc c la Keyword=ollas 
Acá en stackoverflow el código tiene un botón RUN o Ejecutar puedes probar inspeccionar desde acá.